# Passing data between different NSViewController swift OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I need to pass data between two different NSViewController:

```
class PrincipalView: NSViewController {

    var num = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }
fun getNum() -> (Int) {
     return num
}
}
```

How can I get access to *num* from another NSViewController, something like

```
  var num = PrincipalView.getNum()
```

Note: The app is for OS X

Comment: pass the pointer(self) from one NSViewController to the other.  Just remember to include that header file in the other NSViewController and cast the pointer as that class.

Comment: if you would accept the answer thanks...

Answer (score 0):

pass the pointer(self) from one NSViewController to the other. Just remember to include that header file in the other NSViewController and cast the pointer as that class.